# Creating product relations using PHP/Ajax/jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm working on a self-made e-shop CMS and in the backend and I need to be able to create relations between products. When adding a new product I want to be able to open a popup window in which I can select the related products and then, when I close the window, I need the selected items to be sent back to a field on my page (ie comma delimited string with the selected values). It doesnt *HAVE* to be a popup window, I'll be glad to use any other method as well, as long as it does the above.

Which ways can I do this? I know Ajax/jQuery will probably do the trick but I don't have much experience with them.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to achieve that. One of these in the following scenario:

**First:** You have a PHP script that connects to the database and get your data.

```
$query = "your query";
$results  = mysql_query($query);
$yourdata = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results,MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    /* format the data in JSON format*/
}        
echo json_encode(array("yourdata" => $yourdata));
```

**Second:** Using jQuery or JavaScript to make an ajax call to the script and then read the returned data from the PHP script and output it in HTML elements.
Or you you can format the data in your PHP script and use JavaScript to parse it and display it.

I can't show you a complete example here for all that but if you search around you will find a lot of examples.

I also highly recommend, if you want to get started with all of this, [Head First jQuery](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449393217), a fantastic book that gets you started with jQuery.

There are great chapters such as chapters 8 and 9 where you will find how you can use jQuery and ajax to get the data and pass it back.
You will find the example code in [this link](http://thinkjquery.com/). Download the sample code for chapter 8 and 9 and try it.

For the popup window part there are a lot of plugins and there are also jQuery UI try this: [Modal form](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form).

I hope that will be helpful.